# Google Drive - Obtaining the FileSize of a File with Just the FileID

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I need to obtain a file's meta-data from just using the Google Drive FileID only.  The assumption being that I don't have knowledge of the folderID. By just using the `FileID` the API just returns `null` for the `filesize` but the correct values for the other meta-data.

Just to be clear, I can get all the meta data (including filesize) by processing the files within a folder, for example:

```
<?php
/*
* With this example I have the folderID from a Google Drive shared link
*/

 $folderId = "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ggWcacF9qQroZOkhfb3tTEwvBzclccwI?usp=share_link";
 $Auth = new Oauth2Authentication();
 $client = $Auth->GetClient();
 $client = $Auth->initializeClient($client);
 $drive = new DriveService($client);
 $pattern = "/[-\w]{25,}(?!.*[-\w]{25,})/";
 if (preg_match($pattern, $folderId, $match)); // grabs folderID from the url
 
 /*
  * Now list the folder contents
 */
 $responseFiles = $drive->ListFiles($match[0]);
 $files = $responseFiles['files'];
 foreach ($files as $file) {
     $id[] = $file->id;
     $name[] = $file->name;
     $mimeType[] = $file->mimeType;
     $size[] = $file->size; //<- correct file size
 };
 $drive->DownloadFile($id, $name, $size);
```

The code below, which I need to work, returns most of the meta-data except that, as stated above, the `$file->size` is always `null`.  My `DownloadFile` method needs the file size so that it can better handle large files.   Is there anyone who can help me better understand the problem?

```
<?php
/*
* With this example I have the only the fileID from a Google Drive shared link
*/

 $fileId = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EjNk1ijPLKJMwXfzkEIG487HFzx0v80v/view?usp=share_link";
 $Auth = new Oauth2Authentication();
 $client = $Auth->GetClient();
 $client = $Auth->initializeClient($client);
 $drive = new DriveService($client);
 $pattern = "/[-\w]{25,}(?!.*[-\w]{25,})/";
 if (preg_match($pattern, $fileId, $match)); // grabs fileID from the url
 /*
  * Now get the file meta data and download the file
 */
 $fileId = $match[0];
 $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
 $file = $service->files->get($fileId);
 $drive->DownloadFile($file->id, $file->name, $file->size);  //$file->size is always null
```

**Update:** Thanks to @DaImTo I was pointed in the right direction.   The full fileID's details can be obtained by adding

```
array('fields' =>'*')
```

to the argument list of the `$service->files->get` method, i.e.

```
$file = $service->files->get($fileId,array('fields' =>'*'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files.list retuns a list of files with limited response.

```
files": [
{
  "kind": "drive#file",
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
  "id": "1x8-vD-X2wltablGF22Lpwup8VtxNY",
  "name": "Experts Activity Dump go/ExpertsActivities"
},
```

To get the file size either tweek the optimal parameter fields or just use .

```
Fileds=*
```

or

```
$responseFiles = $drive->ListFiles($match[0],array('fields' =>'*'))
```

Comment: Thanks, but the ListFiles for a folder works okay, but how do I apply the "tweeking" to the second example; where I use "$file = $service->files->get($fileId);" ?  Is that possible as I can't see anyway of specifying the opt parameters?

Comment: did you try the same option as I have shown?

Comment: try this https://www.daimto.com/simple-how-to-integrate-google-drive-api-with-php/  I am mobile right now I can't test it

Comment: I tested as requested (the first suggestion), and it gives me what looks like all the files on the drive (which is good to know :-) ) but the filesize returned is still null for the ones I checked.

Comment: I have looked at the code in the link, and I suspect it may return the same result.   It looks straightforward  to test as all I should need to do as add the "size" attribute into the last section of the code.  I will let you know.

Comment: ok let me know if you don't get it I will see if I can find some time to boot a PC

Comment: Thankyou, can you let me know please.  Also, I just check the fileID using this link and it returned the file size okay,  https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get?apix_params=%7B%22fileId%22%3A%221EjNk1ijPLKJMwXfzkDIG487HFzx0v80v%22%2C%22acknowledgeAbuse%22%3Afalse%2C%22projection%22%3A%22FULL%22%7D

Comment: yeah don't use drive v2 please 